# Building stacked bar plot for specific data organisation

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, data-visualization, bioinformatics

I would like to build the stacked bar plot with x-axis representing the number of genomes (or just organisms) and y-axis representing the number of gene clusters, which occur in exact number of genomes. As I know from which organisms these genes came from, I would like each bar to show the impact of each genome in building this bar.

Example of my data:

```
df = data.frame (genomes_involed = c(1,2,2,3,3,1), number_of_genes = c(1,3,2,3,4,2), genome1_genes = c("A","B","*", "B", "A,M","*"), genome2_genes = c("*","C,B","E", "D", "N", "*"), genome3_genes = c("*","*", "L", "H", "O", "P,A"))
```

Where:

rows are gene clusters;

1) the first column show the number of genomes involved in each gene cluster;

2) the second column represents the number of genes in the cluster;

3) columns 3-5 represent concrete names of genes from different genomes;

"*" shows that there are no genes in the cluster for this genome.

It has more or less specific organisation, that's why I am not sure how to put it in the right way, for example in this ggplot function:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = factor(Time), y = Value, fill = factor(Type))) + geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "stack")
```

As the result I want to get 3 bars on x-axis, representing the number of genomes 1,2 or all 3; y-axis representing the number of clusters found in 1, 2 or all the 3 genomes; and show the impact in percentage of each genome in building each concrete bar.

[Desired output for this sample is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OrtFS.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused, but i think you are saying that there are multiple organisms, and each organism has either genome 1, 2, or 3.  You want three bars on the x axis - one for genome 1, one for genome 2, and one for genome 3 - and the stacks will show how many of the organisms with genome 1 had 1 gene cluster, how many 2 gene cluster, and how many had 3 (etc. for each of the other genomes)?

```
df = data.frame (genomes_envolved = c(1,2,2,3,3,1), number_of_genes = c(1,3,2,3,3,2), genome1_genes = c("A","B","*", "B", "A,M","*"), genome2_genes = c("*","C,B","E", "D", "N", "*"), genome3_genes = c("*","*", "L", "H", "O", "P"))

df[df=="*"]<-NA #I changed asterisk to NA
df$genomes_envolved<-as.factor(df$genomes_envolved)
df$number_of_genes<-as.factor(df$number_of_genes)

ggplot(data = df, aes(x = genomes_envolved,fill=number_of_genes)) + geom_bar()
```

[image]

Comment: Dear Emilio, thank you for your answer. Tip with NA seems to be reasonable enough, I did not know that it can be used this way. But probably I did not describe the idea of the plot good enough, so I have edited the sample and added the picture of the expected output.

Comment: Ah, now I understand. You can't do it directly the way the data are set up in this data frame, it needs to be reorganized so that you can tabulate how many genes there are in each genome.